# Ordenamiento de listas de objetos en Java

Tags: java-8, maven, jdeveloper

Buenas tengo una consulta. Estoy comparando dos atributos de una lista, la puntuación y el nombre. Pasa que al querer hacer la prueba unitaria me arroja fail a todas con el mensaje UnsupportedOperationException.
Me estoy perdiendo de algo?

```
public static List<Jugador> ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(List<Jugador> jugadores){
        //TODO: resolver
        
            jugadores.sort(Comparator.comparing(Jugador::getPuntuacion)
                     .reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Jugador::getNombre));
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
               
            }
```

El método static List devuelve una lista pero al colocar el thrown new exception no se puede devolver nada y esto hace que los test no pasen. Me gustaria saber su opinion.
Esto es lo que tengo en la clase Test para poder ver si el método se ejecuta con normalidad.
La clase Test solo la tengo para ejecutar pruebas, si quito el thrown new y la excepción, se ejectuta todo con normalidad, de lo contrario no pasa ningún test.

```
package com.baufest.ingreso.sorting;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SortingTest {
    @Test
    public void sort1Completo() {
        Jugador p1 = new Jugador("Matias", 100);
        Jugador p2 = new Jugador("Alejandro", 100);
        Jugador p3 = new Jugador("Enzo", 50);
        Jugador p4 = new Jugador("Junior", 75);
        Jugador p5 = new Jugador("Pablo", 150);
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadores.add(p1);
        jugadores.add(p2);
        jugadores.add(p3);
        jugadores.add(p4);
        jugadores.add(p5);
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(jugadores);
        Jugador p1Sort = new Jugador("Pablo", 150);
        Jugador p2Sort = new Jugador("Alejandro", 100);
        Jugador p3Sort = new Jugador("Matias", 100);
        Jugador p4Sort = new Jugador("Junior", 75);
        Jugador p5Sort = new Jugador("Enzo", 50);
        List<Jugador> jugadoresSort = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadoresSort.add(p1Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p2Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p3Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p4Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p5Sort);
        
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.size(), jugadoresResult.size());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(0).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(0).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(1).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(1).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(2).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(2).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(3).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(3).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(4).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(4).getNombre());
        
        jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(jugadores);
        assertTrue(jugadoresResult.isEmpty());
        
        jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadores.add(p1);
        jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(jugadores);
        assertEquals(1, jugadoresResult.size());
        assertEquals(p1.getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(0).getNombre());
    }

    @Test
    public void sort1Vacio() {
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(jugadores);
        assertTrue(jugadoresResult.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void sort1Unico() {
        Jugador p1 = new Jugador("Matias", 100);
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadores.add(p1);
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(jugadores);
        assertEquals(1, jugadoresResult.size());
        assertEquals(p1.getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(0).getNombre());
    }

    @Test
    public void sort2Completo() {
        
        Jugador p1 = new Jugador("Matias", 100, 3);
        Jugador p2 = new Jugador("Alejandro", 100, 4);
        Jugador p3 = new Jugador("Enzo", 75, 5);
        Jugador p4 = new Jugador("Junior", 75, 30);
        Jugador p5 = new Jugador("Pablo", 150, 0);
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadores.add(p1);
        jugadores.add(p2);
        jugadores.add(p3);
        jugadores.add(p4);
        jugadores.add(p5);
        
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionPerdidasYNombre(jugadores);
        
        Jugador p1Sort = new Jugador("Pablo", 150, 0);
        Jugador p2Sort = new Jugador("Matias", 100, 3);
        Jugador p3Sort = new Jugador("Alejandro", 100, 4);
        Jugador p4Sort = new Jugador("Enzo", 75, 5);
        Jugador p5Sort = new Jugador("Junior", 75, 30);
        
        List<Jugador> jugadoresSort = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadoresSort.add(p1Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p2Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p3Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p4Sort);
        jugadoresSort.add(p5Sort);


        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.size(), jugadoresResult.size());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(0).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(0).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(1).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(1).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(2).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(2).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(3).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(3).getNombre());
        assertEquals(jugadoresSort.get(4).getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(4).getNombre());
    }

    @Test
    public void sort2Vacio() {
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionPerdidasYNombre(jugadores);
        assertTrue(jugadoresResult.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void sort2Unico() {
        Jugador p1 = new Jugador("Matias", 100);
        List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
        jugadores.add(p1);
        List<Jugador> jugadoresResult = Sorting.ordenarPorPuntuacionPerdidasYNombre(jugadores);
        assertEquals(1, jugadoresResult.size());
        assertEquals(p1.getNombre(), jugadoresResult.get(0).getNombre());
    }


}
```

Comment: Tienes puesto para que te lance una excepción todo el rato, por lo que te lo está enviando continuamente. Por otro lado, avisarte de que el código que proporciones, deberá de estar en el formato correspondiente, por lo que podrías [edit] tu pregunta y copiar el código, en vez de poner fotos

Comment: @Maidagan ya pude editarlo, como podia evitar que me envia excepciones a cada rato?
Pensé en este método.

public static List<Jugador> ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(List<Jugador> jugadores){
     //TODO: resolver
  try {
   jugadores.sort(Comparator.comparing(Jugador::getPuntuacion)
      .reversed()
      .thenComparing(Jugador::getNombre));
  } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  return jugadores;
  //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
         
   }

Answer (score 0):

Intenté manejarlo de esta forma.

```
public static List<Jugador> ordenarPorPuntuacionYNombre(List<Jugador> jugadores){
        //TODO: resolver
        try {
            jugadores.sort(Comparator.comparing(Jugador::getPuntuacion)
                     .reversed()
                     .thenComparing(Jugador::getNombre));
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return jugadores;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
               
            }
```